# Keeping all data around "rollmean" output

Tags: r, zoo, moving-average

I have recently found out that `rollmean` will provide me with the moving average around a number in my matrix.  The problem I have is that my matrix shrinks and I also lose the row names when the function is executed.  For example the matrix `MA.test` as such is quantities per day in the rows (A = Mon, B = Tues, etc.):

```
   > MA.Test
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t
A 49 21  6 27 34 49 21  6 27 34 49 21  6 27 34 49 21  6 27 34
B 35 23 37 47 45 35 23 37 47 45 35 23 37 47 45 35 23 37 47 45
C 40  0 20 10 19 40  0 20 10 19 40  0 20 10 19 40  0 20 10 19
D  8 46 22  3 28  8 46 22  3 28  8 46 22  3 28  8 46 22  3 28
E 30  7  1 42 39 30  7  1 42 39 30  7  1 42 39 30  7  1 42 39
F  9 16 32 14 33  9 16 32 14 33  9 16 32 14 33  9 16 32 14 33
G 48  5 13 15 11 48  5 13 15 11 48  5 13 15 11 48  5 13 15 11
H 12 38 36 18 24 12 38 36 18 24 12 38 36 18 24 12 38 36 18 24
I 43 26 17 44 25 43 26 17 44 25 43 26 17 44 25 43 26 17 44 25
J 41  2 29 31  4 41  2 29 31  4 41  2 29 31  4 41  2 29 31  4
```

When I apply the function for an average covering 3 days each side (which would be using 7, incorporating the day, I would use `rollmean(MA.Test,7)` and label this `MA.Test.1` and get the following:

```
> MA.Test.1 = rollmean(MA.Test,7)
> MA.Test.1
      a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t
[1,] 31 17 19 23 30 31 17 19 23 30 31 17 19 23 30 31 17 19 23 30
[2,] 26 19 23 21 28 26 19 23 21 28 26 19 23 21 28 26 19 23 21 28
[3,] 27 20 20 21 26 27 20 20 21 26 27 20 20 21 26 27 20 20 21 26
[4,] 27 20 21 24 23 27 20 21 24 23 27 20 21 24 23 27 20 21 24 23
```

My queries is two fold:

1. I am aware the output begins with a MA around row D and ends at row G as I will have no values for rows A/B/C or H/I/J as they have insufficient surrounding data; how would I still KEEP these rows in the output with simply an "NA"?
2. I am losing the row names - simple enough for this small example, but my real data set contains +100 rows and these row names are dates; how would I keep the original column names in the output?

My desired final output would look as such:

```
> MA.Test.1 = rollmean(MA.Test,7)
> MA.Test.1
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t
A NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
B NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
C NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
D 31 17 19 23 30 31 17 19 23 30 31 17 19 23 30 31 17 19 23 30
E 26 19 23 21 28 26 19 23 21 28 26 19 23 21 28 26 19 23 21 28
F 27 20 20 21 26 27 20 20 21 26 27 20 20 21 26 27 20 20 21 26
G 27 20 21 24 23 27 20 21 24 23 27 20 21 24 23 27 20 21 24 23
H NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
I NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
J NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Thank you kindly for any solutions offered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fill=NA` to pad with `NA`. Then you can set the `rownames` of the result to that of the input.

```
MA.Test.1 <- rollmean(MA.Test,7,fill=NA)
rownames(MA.Test.1) <- rownames(MA.Test)
```

But if your actual data have Dates as row names, then you could just use zoo (or xts).

```
library(xts)
ma <- MA.Test
rownames(ma) <- Sys.Date()-9:0
# zoo
z <- zoo(ma, as.Date(rownames(ma)))
z1 <- rollmean(z, 7, fill=NA)
# xts
x <- as.xts(ma)
x1 <- rollmean(x, 7, fill=NA)
```

Comment: Note that this works:  `library(zoo); as.data.frame(rollmean(zoo(MA.Test, rownames(MA.Test)), 7))` without `fill=NA`. .It assumes the rownames are in ascending order.

Comment: Hi Joshua, I have the dates as row names, however I used Lubridate earlier in the data manipulation process -the str() denotes them as POSIXct.  Would this impact the approaches you outlined? Thanks

Comment: @Qaribbean: row names cannot be `POSIXct`, they are always character. If the row names have dates and times, then just use `as.POSIXct` instead of `as.Date` in my answer.

Comment: Joshua, this worked!  My apologies, what should have been explained was that the dates (in POSIXct format) were initially the first column and then I used them as the row names and then deleted the column (as the rollmean function would not work across the data frame when the date values were present.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck this method was also useful, thank you!